# Wrap and create divs with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `div` with `Tasks`. Every `Task` is a separate `form`.

```
<div id="tasks">
    <form id="task">...(@task.date = 2013-08-25)...</form>
    <form id="task">...(@task.date = 2013-08-25)...</form>
    <form id="task">...(@task.date = 2013-08-24)...</form>
    <form id="task">...(@task.date = 2013-08-23)...</form>
    <form id="task">...(@task.date = 2013-08-23)...</form>
    <form id="task">...(@task.date = 2013-08-23)...</form>
    <form id="task">...(@task.date = 2013-08-21)...</form>
    <form id="task">...(@task.date = 2013-08-21)...</form>
</div>
```

I want to wrap `Tasks` with the same `date` in separate `div` and to add `div` with header info.

```
<div id="tasks">
    <div class="day_tasks">
        <div class="day_tasks_header">...</div>
        <form id="task">...(@task.date = 2013-08-25)...</form>
        <form id="task">...(@task.date = 2013-08-25)...</form>
    </div>
    <div class="day_tasks">
        <div class="day_tasks_header">...</div>
        <form id="task">...(@task.date = 2013-08-24)...</form>
    </div>
    <div class="day_tasks">
        <div class="day_tasks_header">...</div>
        <form id="task">...(@task.date = 2013-08-23)...</form>
        <form id="task">...(@task.date = 2013-08-23)...</form>
        <form id="task">...(@task.date = 2013-08-23)...</form>
    </div>
    <div class="day_tasks">
        <div class="day_tasks_header">...</div>
        <form id="task">...(@task.date = 2013-08-21)...</form>
        <form id="task">...(@task.date = 2013-08-21)...</form>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's possible to add a `date` to div's class name and to `.wrapAll` divs with the same class in separate div with jQuery, and then `.prepend()` a div with header info on the top of this separate div. But I don't want to put so much view logic from rails side to JS side.

Is it possible to do it with Rails?

My `index.html.erb` is rather simple:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, id: 'tasks') do %>
    <%= render @tasks %>
<% end %>
```

`_task.html.erb` is also a simple `<%= form_for task ... %>`

Comment: Notice that id should not be same for all forms. You can change it as class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) in ruby which I think would help you achieve this. You can group your tasks by date. You'll need to change your rendering approach slightly but, as you say, it'll be neater than doing it in javascript.

So, to group your tasks you can do:

```
grouped_tasks = @tasks.group_by(&:date)
```

Which will return you a hash mapping the date to the tasks that have that date, for example:

```
{ "2013-08-25" => [task1, task2],
  "2013-08-24" => [task3],
  "2013-08-23" => [task4, task5, task6],
  "2013-08-21" => [task7, task8] }
```

You can then iterate over the groupings to build up the view:

```
<div id="tasks">
  <% grouped_tasks.each do |date, tasks| %>
    <div class="day_tasks">
      <div class="day_tasks_header">...</div>
      <% tasks.each do |task| %>
        <%= form_for task ... %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```